# IE 8 and FF Value Conflict

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, button

I have this button

```
<input type="submit" name="forgot_pass" class="submitButton mainPageButton" id="forgotPassButton" value="Forgot Pass" />
```

In Firefox the button value is "Submit" and in Internet Explorer it is "Forgot Pass" (what I set the value to be).

I am really confused why this might happen.

Comment: I just checked with jsfiddle - both are the same with "Forgot Pass" o.O

Comment: I found the problem, it was within my jQuery. I should've looked deeper into the problem before posting this question. I am sorry.

Comment: No worries :) Glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both browsers are showing "Forgot Pass" caption.

http://jsfiddle.net/fb9h3/